# Proof of: "holomorphic forms are closed on compact Kähler manifolds"

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'm looking for an **elementary** proof (if any) of the following

**Statement:** *holomorphic forms are closed on compact Kähler manifolds.*

Any classical reference(s) would be welcome as well as the names of the mathematicians to whom this result should be attributed.

Thanks.

Comment: Won't an holomorphic form be holomorphic (thus closed) in any local chart, thus a closed form ?

Comment: No : the form $z_1dz_2$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb C^2$ but not closed.

Answer (score 11):

Let $\alpha$ be a holomorphic $p$-form, i.e. $\alpha$ is a $(p, 0)$-form which satisfies $\bar{\partial}\alpha = 0$. Note that $\bar{\partial}^*\alpha = 0$, so $\alpha$ is $\bar{\partial}$-harmonic, i.e. $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}}\alpha = 0$. If the manifold is compact and Kähler, then $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}} = \Delta_{\partial}$ so $\Delta_{\partial}\alpha = 0$ and hence $\partial\alpha = 0$. Therefore $d\alpha = \partial\alpha + \bar{\partial}\alpha = 0$, so $\alpha$ is closed.

Comment: what is $\overline{\partial}^*\alpha$?

Comment: The operator $\bar{\partial}^*$ denotes the adjoint of $\bar{\partial}$ and is given by $\bar{\partial}^* = -\ast\bar{\partial}\ast$ where $\ast$ denotes the Hodge star. In this case, it is a map $\bar{\partial}^* : \mathcal{E}^{p,0}(X) \to \mathcal{E}^{p, -1}(X) = \{0\}$ so $\bar{\partial}^*\alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal{E}^{p,0}(X)$.

Comment: Why does $\Delta_\partial \alpha = 0$ imply that $\partial \alpha = 0$?

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain: It's the same argument as in your answer, just for $\partial$ instead of $d$.

Comment: Where do you use compactness?

Comment: @Danny: I know your comment was almost two years ago, but for the record, compactness is needed for the implication $\Delta_{\partial}\alpha = 0 \implies \partial\alpha = 0$ (using an argument analogous to the one in Warlock of Firetop Mountain's answer).

Answer (score 3):

On any Kahler manifold, you have that holomorphic forms are harmonic because of the identity $\Delta = 2\Delta_{\overline{\partial}}$.
Moreover in the **compact** case an harmonic form $\omega $ it is also closed because 
$$ 0 = \langle\Delta\omega,\omega\rangle = || d \omega||^2 + ||d^*\omega||^2 $$
(this is not true in the non-compact case as $d^*$ is just the **formal** adjoint)
it follows that holomorphic forms are closed.