# Holomorphic forms are closed on compact manifold $X$ if $\dim(X)=2$.

Tags: complex-geometry, closed-form, complex-manifolds, hodge-theory, compact-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold and $\dim(X)=2$, $\eta$ is a holomorphic form on $X$. Prove that d$\eta=0$.

I know when $X$ is a compact complex Kähler manifold, [holomorphic forms are closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2438634/proof-of-holomorphic-forms-are-closed-on-compact-k%c3%a4hler-manifolds).

In my case, $X$ may not be a Kähler manifold. To prove that d$\eta=0$, I only need to prove that $\Delta \eta=0$. $\eta$ satisfies $\bar\partial \eta=0$ and $\bar\partial^* \eta=0$. $\eta$ is $\bar\partial$-harmonic. It suffices to show $\eta$ is $\partial$-harmonic. But I can't complete the proof.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to be a compact *complex* manifold?  And $\dim(X)$ is its complex dimension?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\int_X d\eta\wedge\overline{d\eta}$. Check that the integrand is exact, since $d\eta = \partial\eta$ and $d\overline{d\eta} = d\bar\partial\bar\eta = \partial\bar\partial\bar\eta = -\bar\partial\partial\bar\eta = -\bar\partial\overline{\bar\partial\eta} = 0$.